# `ssh [...] sleep 3` (with sshpass) don't close ever

Tags: ssh, sleep

I open an SSH tunnel programatically, with:

```
sshpass -p "my_password" ssh -fN -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes remote_user@remote_server.tld -L 13306:127.0.0.1:3306 sleep 3
```

and works as expected, but don't close after 3 seconds of inactivity.

I take the SSH PID and kill explicitly when the connection is finished; but I prefer the `sleep` version, if can close the tunnel automatically.

The use with `sshpass` maintain the tunnel open or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What about using: `timeout 3 sshpass ...` ? Or you want exactly use an `sshpass` option that shuts down the tunnel after X seconds of inactivity? I mean: you need to clese exactly after 3 seconds or after 3 seconds of inactivity ?

Comment: I need some seconds of inactivity (not exactly 3). `sshpass` finish as soon as is executed, the `ssh` part remains for ever, and I can't do `sshpass [...] timeout 3 ssh [...]`. Correction: I can do `sshpass [...] timeout 3 ssh [...]` but has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

> `-f`
>
> Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.  This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.  This implies -n. The recommended way to start X11 programs at a remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.

and

> `-N`
>
> Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.

Which goes into the background before executing a command (which is suppressed). Therefore it stays in the background. The `sleep` is never run and it waits to be killed.

Comment: Removed `-N` and works perfectly. Thanks.